# Polymer 2.0 Data-Binding Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I'm trying to show the list of all the candidates under their corresponding parties I have stored in my Firebase database. I am using Polymer 2.0 Starter-Kit.

Here's the code:

```
_checkParties() {
      var candidate_list = []
      firebase.database().ref("/candidates/"+this.party.$key).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
              var data = {"key": snap.key, "data": snap.val()}

              var results = Object.keys(data["data"]).map(function(key) {
                return {
                    name: key,
                    value: data["data"][key],
                    key: data["key"]
                };
              })
              candidate_list.push(results[0])
          })
      })
      this.candidates = candidate_list;
  }
```

Basically I'm querying from my firebase the children of that path, then appended them to my `var candidate_list`. Outside the query I then set my `this.candidates` to the array `var candidate_list`.

Here's the code to my template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ candidates }}" as="candidate">
      <div class="card">
          <p>[[candidates]]</p>
          <h3>[[candidate.name]] - [[candidate.value]]</h3>
          <paper-button raised style="color: yellow; background-color: black;" on-tap="_castVote">Vote</paper-button>
      </div>
  </template>
```

The code to my static properties:

```
candidates: {
            type: Array,
            value: []
          }
```

Then my constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
  }
```

I tried adding this to my constructor but it doesn't seem to affect anything:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.candidates = [];
  }
```

The result should be that the cards in my template dom-repeat show all the candidates. Instead I'm getting nothing is being shown.
But when I `console.log` I could see all my candidates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where your `_checkParties` is being called, but it sounds like Polymer isn't aware that you updated the candidates `array`.

I think that the first attempt could be to use the set method, to be sure it's notified of the update, as described [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data). So that would mean to replace your last statement in the method. Instead of

```
this.candidates = candidate_list;
```

you would have

```
this.set('candidates', candidate_list);
```

Another option, that seems to be very well suited for what you're doing would be to have the candidates list as a computed property. So you would just add to your property definition the `'computed'` key:

```
candidates: {
    type: Array,
    value: [],
    computed: '_checkParties(candidatesResponse)',
}
```

and in your method you would have to return the list, instead of overwritting the property, so

```
return candidate_list;
```

instead of the same line mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for the answer!I actually did try `this.set()` but then the `this` wasn't being recognised. I was able to do a work around by doing `var self = this` outside the loop. I haven't tried computed though. Which is better for performance? `computed` or `this.set`?

Comment: @Mikebarson so you're saying that you got it to work by using the set method? BTW, if you're ok with using ES6 you could use the arrow function syntax to avoid binding on the `this` keyword, so you wouldn't need to "cache" your scope in another variable; when it comes to the performance difference from setting the list by using the set method, versus an observer, I don't know if there is any, it just kind of made sense to use a computed property, because that's what actually happens here. But I guess you can use which method suits you best.

Comment: Yes I used the set method. So there's no difference in performance then, alright. Can you clarify what the ES6 syntax is? I'm quite new to this whole system of ES6 stuff. Is it the one like this? `function() =>`?

Comment: ES6 is a set of updates to the JavaScript language, that provide a lot of new features and syntactic sugar. One of them is the arrow function, that you can see described here: https://mzl.la/1rrAsL3 where there's a paragraph "No binding of this" that explains why that would be an alternative. But you should decide if you want to use the ES6 syntax, because it's not yet supported by all the browsers. Usually people use it only if they decide only to support modern browsers or if they save a build process that runs a transpiler.

Comment: Thanks for this! Accepting this answer.